# Parallel Random forest in R utilizing CARET package

Tags: r, r-caret

I am utilizing one of the regression technique parallel random forest named as `method="parRF"` in R under the `caret` package; it seems to work faster than regular random forest. May I kindly request the difference in the implementation detail that speed up the process.

Any link to document explaining parallel random forest algorithm and implementation would be of great help.

Comment: You could also check Mitchell's publication on the subject [here](http://www.hector.ac.uk/cse/distributedcse/reports/sprint02/sprint02_rf.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

It is a parallel implementation using your machine's multiple cores and an MPI package.
Check out the page on parallel implementations at http://caret.r-forge.r-project.org/parallel.html and of course the package's CRAN page.  I hope these are enough detail for you.